# Is it possible in Entity Framework MVC application to run .sql scripts on a different database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, database-connection

Is it possible that from within my Asp.net MVC (EF) application i connect to another database, run some scripts and then close the connection.

Since this application already connects to a default database as soon as i run the application. Can i then connect to another one simultaneously (from a controller action) for a while and run some scripts on that one and then close connection?

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: how can i go about it?

Comment: Read about `SqlCommand`

Comment: What's the point of using an ORM like EF just so to run adhoc SQL queries?  You are arguably better off just using something like ADO.NET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples

Comment: Besides using EF on our whole project. As per project requirement, we need an admin page (mvc view) where admin can specify connection details and click install which should run scripts in the background. Hope this answers your question

Comment: Google _right tool for the job_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So This is what i simply did in my controller

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Install()
    {
        foreach (ConnectionStringSettings c in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
        {


                //get all files from this folder except insert and mysql create scripts and then run each of them
                string script = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Test.sql");
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(c.ConnectionString);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    MySqlScript m = new MySqlScript(conn, script);
                    m.Delimiter = "$$";
                    m.Execute();
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch { }

        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what happened to _"Besides using EF on our whole project"_?

Comment: @MickyD we wanted something like a url that can be typed in by admins to run some scripts on any db of our choice even when we r not logged in. Once logged in, the EF establishes its connection with a database and business goes as usual. My confusion was if we are logged in would it be possible to establish another connection and that also without using EF. For which Shyju answered yes. So i started trying. Aron's answer also helped. hope this answers your question

Comment: But your answer **isnt** using EF

Comment: thats why i said "Besides using EF" :)

Comment: Ugh you make zero sense

Answer (score 1):

Setup a separate context with the connection string for the other database and use on of the options below.

**Writing SQL queries for non-entity types**

A SQL query returning instances of any type, including primitive types, can be created using the SqlQuery method on the Database class. For example:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogNames = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>( 
                       "SELECT Name FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList(); 
}
```

The results returned from SqlQuery on Database will never be tracked by the context even if the objects are instances of an entity type.

**Sending raw commands to the database**

Non-query commands can be sent to the database using the ExecuteSqlCommand method on Database. For example:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( 
        "UPDATE dbo.Blogs SET Name = 'Another Name' WHERE BlogId = 1"); 
}
```

Note that any changes made to data in the database using ExecuteSqlCommand are opaque to the context until entities are loaded or reloaded from the database.

**Output Parameters**

If output parameters are used, their values will not be available until the results have been read completely.

Comment: I have multiple contexts already setup but here i needed to simply run the scripts weather i am logged into the application or not

Comment: Are the scripts in actual files? Can you clarify how they would be triggered? In the question you said from and admin page and you just mentioned they would be triggered when you are not logged in.

Comment: Yes i have shared complete code that is working in my answer